# Fast sequential logging for webservices

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, logging

My webservices are as structured as follows:

1. Receive request
2. Parse and validate input
3. Do actual webservice
4. Validate output

I am primarily using logging for debugging purposes, if something went wrong I want to know what the request was so I can hope to reproduce it (ie. send the exact same request).

Currently I'm logging to a MySQL database table. After 1. a record is created, which is updated with more info after 2. and 3. and cleaned up after 4. (Logs of successful requests are pruned).

I want the logging to be as quick and painless as possible. Any speed up here will considerably improve overall performance (round trip of each request).

I was thinking of using `INSERT DELAYED` but I can't do that because I need the `LAST_INSERT_ID` to update and later delete the log record, or at least record the status of the request (ie. success or error) so I know when to prune.

I could generated a unique id myself (or at least an id that is 'unique enough') but even then I wont know the order of the `DELAYED` statements and I might end up trying to update or delete a record that doesn't exist yet. And since `DELAYED` also removes the ability to use `NUM_AFFECTED_ROWS` I can't check if the queries are effected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally people log to a txt file. Log everything with a common guid for each request so you can later post process the file. Logging directly to a db is overkill and slow.

Comment: Logging to a database is not considerable slower than logging to a file, I'd imagine, as both will do I/O operations. I don't see how logging to a database is overkill. However, I *also* don't see why it is necessary to mutate the record three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I can probably just do a `REPLACE DELAYED` and do the pruning some other time. (with a `DELETE DELAYED`).

Answer (score 0):

When you say pruned im assuming if it was a success your removing the record? If so I think it would be better for you if you had a Java object storing the information instead of the database as the process unfolds then if an exception occurs you log the information in the object to the database all at once.

If you wanted to take it further, I did something similiar to this, I have a service which queues the logging of audit data and inserts the info at a steady pace so if the services are getting hammered were not clogging the DB with logging statements, but if your only logging errors that would probably be overkill.

Comment: I'm using PHP, I don't see how I can easily implement queuing.